# How to show list of posts with custom field value (a date) that are coming soon

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, date

I have a custom post type called `client` and it has a custom field of `next_due_date`, that is a date without time. I want to have a list of posts that have a next due date that is coming up soon. I tried creating a page template called "due soon" with this code (including changes suggested by Tim Malone):

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'client',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'       => 'next_due_date',
    'meta_query'     => array(array(
        'key'     => 'meta_value_num',
        'value'   => date('YY-mm-dd',strtotime("today")+(7*60*60*24)),
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type'    => 'DATE'
    ))
));
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    responsive_entry_before(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php responsive_entry_top(); ?> 
        <h2 class="entry-title post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>  
        <div class="post-entry">
            <?php echo "File # : " . get_post_meta($post->ID,'file_number',true) . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo "File Status : " . get_post_meta($post->ID,'file_status', true) . "<br />"; ?>
        </div><!-- end of .post-entry -->
        <div class="post-meta">
            <?php responsive_post_meta_data(); ?>
            <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
                <span class="comments-link">
                <span class="mdash">&mdash;</span>
                <?php comments_popup_link( 
                    __( 'No Comments &darr;', 'responsive' ), 
                    __( '1 Comment &darr;', 'responsive' ), 
                    __( '% Comments &darr;', 'responsive' ) ); ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- end of .post-meta -->

        ________________________________
        <?php responsive_entry_bottom(); ?>
    </div><!-- end of #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
    <?php responsive_entry_after();
endwhile;
```

I haven't been able to get it to output anything, let alone figured out how to define coming soon (say 7 days).

Here's the code I'm using to count the post types and ones with a field set to open:

```
global $wpdb;
$meta_key = 'file_status';
$meta_value = 'open';

$sql = "SELECT count(DISTINCT pm.post_id)
FROM $wpdb->postmeta pm
JOIN $wpdb->posts p ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
WHERE pm.meta_key = '$meta_key'
AND pm.meta_value = '$meta_value'
AND p.post_type = 'client'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
";
$count = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('client');
$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
echo "Number of Clients: " . $published_posts;
echo "<p>Open Files: $count</p>";
```

I'd love to also count the ones with due dates coming up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `the_post()` doesn't actually output anything - it just sets up the post data ready to output. You'll need to do something like this to show the posts:

```
<?php
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

There's several more tags you can use and you'll want to format the HTML around them to display how you want to, let me know if you need guidance on that too.

As for the query, you'll probably find this very useful: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

You're pretty close with the ordering, but to limit your posts returned to anything within the next 7 days you'll need to use a meta_query. Here's how you do that:

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'client',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'       => 'next_due_date',
    'meta_query'      => array(array(
            'relation'=> 'AND',
            array(
                 'key'     => 'next_due_date',
                 'value'   => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("today")+(7*60*60*24)),
                 'compare' => '<=',
                 'type'    => 'DATE'
            ),
            array(
                 'key'     => 'next_due_date',
                 'value'   => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("today")),
                 'compare' => '>=',
                 'type'    => 'DATE'                     
            )
    ))
));
?>
```

I haven't tested this code but I think it's correct - let me know how you go. The 7 days is defined by the `7*60*60*24` - 60 seconds x 60 minutes x 24 hours x 7 days.

**UPDATED as per comments to also filter out posts in the past**

Comment: That looks like it's correct. I tried it but the output was still blank. based on the date format in the DB Ichanged Y-m-d to YY-mm-dd, still nothing. heres the full code based on what you posted:  Edit,it wouldn't let me put the code here so i put it into the next answer

Comment: Sorry... I'm silly, I didn't use the right key. I've just changed the `key` in the `meta_query` to `next_due_date`, try it again now!

Comment: Also, the format for `date()` is based on http://php.net/date - `YY-mm-dd` will not work because it will print out everything twice (eg. Y corresponds to the 4 character year, so YY will print out 20152015). If the database value is only two characters for the year and the above still isn't working, you might want to try lowercase y instead which will print out a two character year - eg. 15. However I'm fairly certain your database value will be four characters.

Comment: yup that was it. it works perfectly now. thank you. Is there a way to count the number of posts that are within the date range? I am adding the code to my original question that I use to count the number of posts in my custom type and how many have a yes/no field set to open. I'd love to be able to also show a count of ones with due dates coming up

Comment: Oh I just noticed that when the due date passes it still shows in the list. Is there a way to filter past due ones out?

Comment: Re counting - this is kindof an additional question (you might want to post it separately?) but if you need to display the count at the same time as running the loop we've already spoken about, you can simply use `echo $loop->found_posts`.

Comment: Re filtering out the past due ones, you can extend the meta_query so it filters on more than one condition. I've updated the code in my answer above. Untested so please let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes the changes worked perfectly. thank you again. I used parts from your code and your echo solution to create a function to output the count